# Paypal IPN para cancelamento pagamento recorrente

Tags: java, jsf, aplicação-web

Obtive o seguinte código do git hub da PayPal. Estou realizando pagamentos recorrentes e gostaria de receber notificação no sistema quando houver cancelamento. Assim, poderia bloquear o fornecimento de meus serviços caso o usuário cancele. Tenho o código do servlet, mas não sei como fazê-lo responder no meu sistema em JSF. Já mapeei no web.xml.

```
package br.com.spacnet.util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.paypal.core.LoggingManager;
import com.paypal.ipn.IPNMessage;
import br.com.spacnet.util.Configuration;

public class IPNListenerServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 /* 
 * receiver for PayPal ipn call back.
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // For a full list of configuration parameters refer in wiki page. 
        // (https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-java/wiki/SDK-Configuration-Parameters)
        Map<String,String> configurationMap =  Configuration.getConfig();
        IPNMessage  ipnlistener = new IPNMessage(request,configurationMap);
        boolean isIpnVerified = ipnlistener.validate();
        String transactionType = ipnlistener.getTransactionType();
        Map<String,String> map = ipnlistener.getIpnMap();

        LoggingManager.info(IPNListenerServlet.class, "******* IPN (name:value) pair : "+ map + "  " +
                "######### TransactionType : "+transactionType+"  ======== IPN verified : "+ isIpnVerified);
    }
}
```

Meu web.xml está dessa forma:

```
 <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>IPNListenerServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>IPNListenerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sample.ipn.IPNListenerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>IPNListenerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/IPNListener</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Você deve mapear seu Servlet com o pacote correto, no seu caso `br.com.spacnet.util` e não `com.sample.ipn`.

Comment: Obrigado, CesarMiguel. Mas mesmo mapeando corretamente agora, quando chamo o endereço http://localhost:8080/meusite/administrador/IPN/ipnMensagem.jsp, na janela de saída do Tomcat não é impresso nada...

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que tenha duas coisas erradas:

1. O mapeamento do `Servlet` está errado. O `<servlet-class>` deve ser `<servlet-class>br.com.spacnet.util.IPNListenerServlet</servlet-class>`, já que o pacote da classe do `Servlet` está dessa forma.
2. O Acesso está errado. Se está usando o Browser para acessar o `IPNListenerServlet`, esta fazendo uma requisição `GET` para um `Servlet` que só atende requisições `POST` (método `doPost` foi implementado), e além disso a url está errada.

   Se o `context-root` da sua aplicação for `meusite` (podendo ser `/`), acredito que deverá fazer uma requisição `POST`, ou usando o `curl` ou um `HttpClient`, para o endereço:

   > `localhost:8080/_seu_context-root_/IPNListener`

   Porque o seu mapeamento do `Servlet` no `web.xml` está com:

   ```
   <url-pattern>/IPNListener</url-pattern>
   ```

   Outra alternativa, seria usar a anotação [`@WebServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafu.html), para configurar seu `Servlet`, mas para isso precisa rodar em um `Servlet Container` que implemente a versão 3.0. Se esse for o caso, seu `Servlet` ficaria:

   ```
   @WebServlet("/IPNListener")
   public class IPNListenerServlet extends HttpServlet
   ```

   Sem a necessidade de configurar ele no `web.xml`.

Para mais detalhes sobre a API de `Servlets` dê uma olhada em [Java Servlet Technology do Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/servlets.htm#BNAFD) ou [Java Servlet Technology do Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html)

---

Não entendi muito bem porque usa a página:

> localhost:8080/meusite/administrador/IPN/ipnMensagem.jsp

Porque em geral o endpoint registrado para o `IPN` do *Paypal* só precisa responder com um código de status. E isso pode ser feito diretamente pelo `Servlet` usando o [`HttpServletResponse.setStatus`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setStatus(int)), não é necessário dar `forward` para uma nova página.

Em relação ao status:

1. Use o status 200 para informar que a requisição foi processada corretamente.
2. Qualquer outro valor é considerado como erro e a notificação `IPN` é feita novamente em outro momento.